# How to store JSON object in a variable?

Tags: angular

I have service which is getting the JSON data (object) in the form response.
I want to store that JSON object in the storeCrossChannelData variable.
How can I achieve this?

```
this.crossChannelSuccessComparison.getCrossChannelData().subscribe(response=>{
     this.storeCrossChannelData = response
})
console.log(this.storeCrossChannelData);
```

Comment: I think you already have stored response into your variable, but your `console.log` is being called before response.

Answer (score 1):

the console.log is not displaying the returned value because it is called before the service return the data try calling the console.log inside the subscribe like this

```
this.crossChannelSuccessComparison.getCrossChannelData().subscribe(response=>{ 
        this.storeCrossChannelData = response
        console.log(this.storeCrossChannelData);
     })
```

Comment: or  JSON.stringify(response) to see what the response is holding